# Does file extension letter case matter for MIME types?

Tags: java, servlets

I stumbled on this today:

```
String fileName = "test.JPG";
servletContext.getMimeType(fileName);  // null
```

Obvious fix:

```
servletContext.getMimeType(fileName.toLowerCase());  // image/jpeg
```

Am I right to not bother about the file extension letter case when detecting the MIME type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already provided the example in your question, Let me explain why this is happening.

If you are using **Tomcat**, you **need to bother** about the case when detecting mimeType.

Why?

Tomcat is storing mimeTypes in a **HashMap** called mimeMappings.

**Key for HashMap is case-sensitive.**

Below code block is taken from `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext`

```
 private HashMap<String, String> mimeMappings =
434         new HashMap<String, String>();
```

You know keys in the java.util.HashMap are case sensitive. It means you can keep both "abc" and "ABC" as keys in the same map.

**See this example.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("abc", "abc");
  map.put("xyz", "xyz");
  map.put("ABC", "ABC");

  System.out.println(map);
}
Output
{ABC=ABC, abc=abc, xyz=xyz}
```

**Info**: That's why case in-sensitive maps [exists](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/CaseInsensitiveMap.html) in **Apache Commons**.

Comment: So it shouldn't matter but because of the Tomcat implementation it does.  I'll stick with my `.toLowerCase()` fix.